# why I get ErrorException: Attempt to assign property 'lastMessage' of non-object with larevel API?

Tags: arrays, laravel, api, sorting, get

Hello everyone actually I'm using laravel API and I'm trying to get this response:

```
chatsContacts: Array(2)
0:
about: "Cake pie jelly jelly beans. Marzipan lemon drops halvah cake. Pudding cookie lemon drops icing"
avatar: "/static/media/avatar-s-2.d21f2121.jpg"
chat:
id: 1
lastMessage:
message: "If it takes long you can mail me at my mail address."
senderId: 11
time: "2022-06-05T22:55:42.271Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
unseenMsgs: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
fullName: "Felecia Rower"
id: 1
role: "Frontend Developer"
status: "offline"
```

as what you are seeing the chat is inside chatsContacts and the lastMessage is inside chat.
I did an attempt to get this response but I get :  `ErrorException: Attempt to assign property 'lastMessage' of non-object`
this is the code:

```
 function listChats($id){
        $types= chat::all()->where('userId', $id);
        $c= chat::all()->where('userId', $id);
        $d=  chat::all()->where('userId', $id);

        foreach ($types as $chats) {
            $chats->chatsContacts = chat::all()->where('userId', $chats->userId); 
        }
        foreach ($c as $chats) {
            $chats->chat = DB::table('chats')->where('id', $chats->id)->get();
            
        foreach ($chats as $m) {
            $m->lastMessage = DB::table('chats')->select('message','time','senderId')->orderBy('time', 'asc')
            ->skip(0)->take(1)->get();
        
        }}
        foreach ($d as $chats) {
            $chats->profileUser = chat::all()->where('userId', $chats->userId); ;    
        }            

                
        return ['chatsContacts' => $types, 'contacts' => $c, 'profileUser' => $d];
  }
```

I would be veryyy thankful if I get a push to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach ($chats as $m) {
        $m->lastMessage = DB::table('chats')->select('message','time','senderId')->orderBy('time', 'asc')
        ->skip(0)->take(1)->get();
    }}
```

what is $chats in this line?? maybe this is the reason you get error?

i suggest you to combine you data after all the foreach done.

like this
`$responsedata['whatever'] = $yourdata`
`$responsedata['whatever2'] = $yourdata2`

then you can `return $responsedata`

Answer (score 0):

Because `::all()` returns array not object. Try to change

```
$types= chat::where('userId', $id)->get();
```